# Constrained optimization with a Proportional-Integral-Derivative (PID) controller

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

My engineering colleagues have devised an interesting approach to equality-constrained optimization.  I.e. they wish to solve the problem $\min_x f(x)$ subject to the constraint $g(x) = 0$ where $f, g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions. Let us say that this optimization problem is well-posed, has a solution, and so on.

I have suggested one of many standard approaches, the augmented Lagrangian algorithm.  But upon explaining the augmented Lagrangian algorithm to my colleagues, they saw a parallel with a technique they are familiar with: namely PID control.  As a consequence, they have proposed the following approach to equality-constrained optimization.  It is an iteration where
\begin{align*}
x_{n+1} &= x_{n} - \alpha \big( \nabla f(x_n) + \mu_n \nabla g (x_n) \big) \\
%
\mu_{n+1} &= \mathrm{PID}\big[ g, \{ x_k\}_{k=1\ldots n} \big] \, .
\end{align*}
The parameter $\alpha$ is a positive step-size parameter which for now we just take to be small enough. The key is how $\mu_n$ is updated: here $\mu_n$ is treated as a sequence of "control parameters" that are designed to cause the "error" $g(x_n)$ to converge to zero.  In other words:

$$\mathrm{PID}\big[ g, \{ x_k\}_{k=1\ldots n} \big] := \gamma_1 g(x_n) + \gamma_2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} g(x_k) + \gamma_3 \left\langle \nabla g(x_n), x_{n+1} - x_n \right\rangle   \, . $$

The parameters $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3$ are tuned to achieve convergence using the "usual" techniques found in feedback control textbooks.

My question is: can this possibly work? Note that if this method converges, then it seems to be converging to a KKT point.

Thank you.

Comment: Interesting idea! I know a lot of works that uses control theory to model an optimization algorithm as a feedback controller, but never saw an algorithm that uses directly a PID control to achieve convergence... Did you make any progress on this work?

Comment: No I did not.  It's been on the shelf for a while...  Could you point me to your 'favourite' reference work in this field?  I'd like to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! This recent [work](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03615) analyzes optimization algorithms by using IQC, a tool from robust control theory.

Comment: A recent paper from I. Ross may also interest you: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09004

Comment: To contrast the problem statements:Engineering the PID seeks good static parameters for closed loop stability.  Search for an optimum tends to vary parameters as the search area is refined and is not robust - it relies on the answer being fixed.  High dimension problems make Lyapunov stability challenging.